# Complex Numbers and Naive Fourier Transform (C++)

Tags: c++, image, transform, fft, complex-numbers

I'm trying to get fourier transforms to work, I have to do it for an assignment and I think I have it to where it should be working and i'm not sure why it's not. I think it has something to do with the complex numbers since 'i' is involved. I've looked at many references and I understand the formula but i'm having trouble programming it. this is what i have so far

```
void NaiveDFT::Apply( Image & img )
{
    //make the fourier transform using the naive method and set that to the image.
    Image dft(img);
    Pixel ** dftData = dft.GetImageData();
    Pixel ** imgData = img.GetImageData();
    for(unsigned u = 0; u < img.GetWidth(); ++u)
    {
        for(unsigned v = 0; v < img.GetHeight(); ++v)
        {
            std::complex<double> sum = 0;
            for(unsigned x = 0; x < img.GetWidth(); ++x)
            {
                for(unsigned y = 0; y < img.GetHeight(); ++y)
                {
                    std::complex<double> i = sqrt(std::complex<double>(-1));
                    std::complex<double> theta = 2 * M_PI * (((u * x) / img.GetWidth()) + ((v * y) / img.GetHeight()));
                    sum += std::complex<double>(imgData[x][y]._red) * cos(theta) + (-i * sin(theta));
                    //sum += std::complex<double>(std::complex<double>(imgData[x][y]._red) * pow(EULER, -i * theta));

                }
            }
            dftData[u][v] = (sum.imag() / (img.GetWidth() * img.GetHeight()));
        }
    }
    img = dft;
}
```

I have a few test images i'm testing this with and i'm either getting like an all black image or like, an all gray image.

I've also tried the sum of e^(-i*2*PI*(x*u*width + y*v*height) * 1/width * height which gets the same result as expected although it's still not the desiered output.

I've also tried the sum.real() number and that doesn't look right either

if anyone has any tips or can point me in the right direction, that'd be great, at this point, i just keep trying different things and checking the output until I get what I should be getting.

thanks.

Comment: `i` is just `std::complex< >(0,1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there can be a problem during the multiplication with the complex term. The line:

```
sum += std::complex<double>(imgData[x][y]._red) * cos(theta) + (-i * sin(theta));
```

should be:

```
sum += std::complex<double>(imgData[x][y]._red) * ( cos(theta) + -i * sin(theta));
```

Moreover, while calculating theta you need to use double precision:

```
std::complex<double> theta = 2 * M_PI * ((((double)u * x) / (double)(img.GetWidth())) + (((double)v * y) / (double)(img.GetHeight())));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that and I get the same output. I think it has something to do with the multiplication with the complex term as well. imgData[x][y]._red is a float, the image is only gray scale so all of the color values should be the same so i'm only using the red value. i'm also using unsigned values in there as well to calculate theta and i'm not sure if that's messing up.

Comment: casting those things to a double made it look different! but i don't think it's correct yet. thanks!

Comment: @user2013535, interpretation of the fft of an image is hard by just looking. Normally you should see some bright regions on the corners and dark regions in the middle.

Comment: yea, i see stuff, but i'm testing with an image i know the output of, it looks close so maybe i have it correct? i'm not entirely sure

Comment: @user2013535, probably it is correct, if  you take inverse fft you should get the original image. That is the criterion.

Comment: I took the inverse of it and applied that and I got an image that's close to the original but not exactly. it looked like there was a copy rotated 180 degrees and translated down and right.